# Просмотр разметки за экраном телефона в режиме design (редактирование xml разметки)?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, прокрутка, design

Здравствуйте,

создаю разметку для андроид устройств под разные размеры экрана. Т.к.
загружать каждый раз приложение, чтобы посмотреть результат в андроид устройстве достаточно долго, хотел бы все настроить в режиме дизайна в 
Android Studio.

В приложении страница достаточно длинная, поэтому на экране телефона
все приложение не помещается, в связи с этим использую прокрутку 
(ScrollView). При запуске приложения прокрутка работает
нормально. Однако когда я редактирую xml разметку в режиме design
там как такового прокрутки нет. Получается вся разметка, которая находится за экраном мне для просмотра не доступна.

Можно ли как то прокрутить экран, чтобы увидеть разметку за экраном
смартфона в режиме design при редактировании xml разметки (layout) ?

Заранее, большое спасибо всем за помощь.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В версии Android Studio до 2.1 включительно прокрутка в визуальном дизайнере невозможна.

В новой версии Android Studio 2.2, которая была представлена на днях и сейчас доступна в виде Preview, редактор визуальной разметки претерпел очень существенные изменения и теперь такая возможность появилась (скролл осуществляется колесиком мыши)

[image: scrn]

как видите на скриншоте представление прокручено до нижнего виджета (TimePicker)

Comment: @ pavlofff, спасибо большое за ответ, теперь все стало ясно.